# Is there a universal connection between localizable measure $μ$ and action $act$?

Tags: measure-theory, category-theory

I wish to understand if is possible to build a function 'bridge' between $μ$ [measure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localizable+measure) and $act$ [action](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action) definitions because I did not find any direct connection or a way to build a own category. 
Only [universal connection](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S131951661630024X/1-s2.0-S131951661630024X-main.pdf?_tid=2045cc60-f89c-4b45-81e0-7de3a4fafc12&acdnat=1524395885_4997ca3fec47ed9bbec44efdb112ed66) that I find is only for finite dimensional Lie group $G$. Ehresmann or Cartan connection is still no sufficient because it works like a *version* of notion of connection.

Concept of a working $μ$-$act$ category is hard to figure out because I really don't understand from where point we deep start within: group cohomology, Homotopy category of chain complexes, [inhabited set](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inhabited+set) ?

> An inhabited set is the special case of an internally inhabited object in the topos $\text{Set}$

Please guide me to formalize the idea by identifying the most correct categories.